# 'Execution failed for task ':amplify_core:compileDebugKotlin' ' error message in Flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, android-studio, aws-amplify

My Windows updated and my app wouldn't run because I had to update a few things and managed to sort the issues that arose out. My app stopped compiling again and turns out I had to redownload flutter and it started compiling again. And now it's back to not compiling, this error, however, has become difficult for me to solve.

This is the error I get when I try to compile my app.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (26, 1): Class 'AtomicResult' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun error(p0: String, p1: String?, p2: Any?): Unit defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (54, 5): 'error' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (66, 26): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':amplify_core:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried migrating code to AndroidX, upgrading flutter, flutter channel is stable. I need help.

Below is the result of flutter doctor.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889])
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at C:\source\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (5 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.0)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.3.32804.467
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 104.0.5112.81
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 104.0.1293.54

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!


C:\Users>flutter channel
Flutter channels:
  master
  beta
* stable
```

Answer (score 0):

In your project folder, look for the build.gradle file at the root of your Android directory and upgrade to the latest version of Kotlin. For the moment the version is at 1.7.10, so go to the Kotlin website and check the last version released. In the file it will look like this:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10
```

Comment: I have upgraded to the latest version of Kotlin ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10 and I get the same error message.  @YounessDominique

Comment: You can change your channel from Master to Stable.

Comment: It's on stable. Not sure what to do now @YounessDominique